# Regular Expression won't extract numbers delimited by white space

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression and would like to parse out all numbers that are only delimited by white space (or ^ or $ if at start or end of line)

```
([\s]|^)([0-9]+)([\s]|$)
```

It only parses every other numbers word. Eg.
**201638** abcdef **800** 201224 abcdef **800** 200

What am I doing wrong?

https://regex101.com/r/pB4gH0/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use \b to match only word boundaries:

```
(\b[0-9]+\b)
```

https://regex101.com/r/tG6tD9/1

In your regex you could not match two consecutives numbers because the space between them was "eaten" by the first number.